# enable & disable Gradle offline mode?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I have this problem when I try to connect with 'Firebase' 
[They ask me to disable 'Gradle' offline mode and Sync project

```
'''dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'
         }'''
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOe6F.png)

and when I Disable 'Gradle' 
[They ask me to enable 'Gradle' offline mode and Sync project

```
''' dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'
         }'''
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JjEF.png)
Note : I unchecked the offline mode

Answer (score 0):

You should keep online mode enabled. As the access to Firebase has been forbidden (code 403) for some reason the problem might be wrong API key.

Comment: OK what should I do?? to Solve this Problem